# MS Access refuses to create correct lookup relationship

Tags: microsoft-access

In my database I have one table "data" with a `short text` field "test".  I want this to be a `lookup`, getting its values from the `short text` "test" field of another table "sims".  I run through all the usual `lookup wizard` stuff, only to find, first of all, that Access has changed my `short text` field to a `number`.  Trying to figure this out, looking at the table in `design view`, I look in the `lookup tab` at the bottom of the page and I see for the `Row Source`:

```
SELECT [sims].[ID], [sims].[test] FROM [sims];
```

So, if I understand the SQL, it is taking options for the `lookup` from the sims "test" field, which I want, *and* the sims "ID" field which I *absolutely do not want*.  I suppose that since "ID" is a `number`, Access thought it had to change the type of my "test" field to `number` to match it?  I have triple checked to make sure that I have in no way selected "ID" in the `lookup wizard` when I try to create the lookup.  Access is adding "ID" into the mix all on its own.

I have tried editing the SQL by hand to get rid of the "ID" field.  I am able to do this.  But then I try to enter short text data into the "test" field via the lookup, and Access tells me that text data won't work in a number field.  So I try to force the format to change from number to text and Access tells me I can't do that because the field is in a relationship.  Catch 22.

Why does Access think it knows better than I do?  How do I get it to stop and give me what I want?